# Basement insulation under cantilever

Tags: insulation, basement

I have a currently unfinished basement in a rather new home.  There are a few places that have bay windows, or cantilevers that currently have only a bit of pink insulation thrown in fro the basement.  From what I can tell, the wall up there, plus the floor (sill box) are the part that is outside the house exposed to the elements.

At first, I was thinking of putting some XPS foam along the top, bottom, and the inside wall and stuffing it with some insulation and sealing it.  But then I read this article: [What material should I use to insulate floor over a bumpout?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/3287/what-material-should-i-use-to-insulate-floor-over-a-bumpout)
 which seems to indicate that I don't want to completely seal it, but instead just insulate the bottom and wall area.

What do you think?

Also, I plan on eventually finishing the basement and using spray foam as insulation.  So anything I do now, I'd want to be able to know that I could remove if needed.

Comment: I'd say [mohlsen's answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/3385/33) to the question you linked to, answers your question.

Comment: Yeah, I just wonder why everyone else seems to suggest closing it off completely.  Anyway, what should I use to stick the xps sheets in?  Tape?  Foam along seam?